# PHP Array variable to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have $test as php array type variable, I want to use that variable in javascript code to check array is empty or not, how can I achieve this? OR how can I convert PHP array variable to Javascript array variable.

Comment: The sort answer is you can not. You can not mix js and php code. Can you please post some of you code to help us understand better what you are asking for?. Can you present an example of the data flow, to understand the interactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
var jsarray = <?php json_encode($php_array)?>;
```

Find [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of array:

```
alert(jsarray.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for that. it converts a php array to json notation

Comment: "or how can i convert a PHP array variable to Javascript array variable?". I'm pretty sure json_encode does that for you. Echo it in the page in the right place, et voila. Is it a vague answer: yes, since it is a vague question. If people don't provide code, they can't honestly expect me to give them 30 examples while they could've googled those themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `json_encode`

```
<?php
$test = array('val');
$js_var = json_encode($test);
?>


<script>
    var test = <?= $js_var; ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good habbit but it will work. THis is just to check if it has value or not
In a php file you might want to put

```
<?php
$my_arr = array();

echo '<script>';
echo  'var has_value ='.count($my_arr) >0?1:0;
echo '</script>'
?>

<script>
   if(has_value==1){
          alert('has value')
   }else{
          alert('no value')
   }
</script>
```

write this on thes same php file